# LT1683 output dropping and compensation

Tags: dc-dc-converter, push-pull

I've done the design using the datasheet of the lt1683 however from the simulation whenever I provide a step input to the load it drops more than I'd like from ~18V to ~16V.

The input to the converter will be 4 series connected 18650 batteries ranging from 13V to 16.8V.

The output is designed to be 18V at 0.5A.

[image]

I can share all the calculations if anyone would like to see the calcs. The output voltage comes out to the expected value. However here is what happens when I step in a 500mA load. I do expect a drop just not this significant.

Here is the waveform

[image]

The peak is 18.85V

[image]

It drops to 16.83V

[image]
Furthermore, I am not sure how to go about compensating this device. I have played around with compensation values but no real difference is seen in output. The compensation value is the value that the ltspice example had in.

To summarize the questions:

1. How do I get the output to drop less than it currently is? At this point it looks like the go-to solution might be a feedforward capacitor?
2. How do I select the compensation values?